# A question about applying a neural network on a specified dimension using PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm wondering about how to do the following thing:

If I have a `torch.tensor` `x` with shape `(4,5,1)` how can apply a neural network using `PyTorch` on the *last* dimension?

Using the standard procedure, the model is flattening the entire tensor into some new tensor of shape `(20,1)` but this is not actually what I want.

Let's say we want some output features of dimension `64`, then I would like to obtain a new object of shape `(4,5,64)`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = torch.randn(4, 5, 1)
print(x.size())

# https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html
m = nn.Linear(1, 64)

y = m(x)
print(y.size())
```

result:

```
torch.Size([4, 5, 1])
torch.Size([4, 5, 64])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).